# Why does router.navigate leave me on blank page with no error message?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I am building an angular2 SPA. I am using the built in router component, and I have implemented a routeGuard. As is usual for this kind of guard, I check if the user is logged in, and if he isn't then I wish to send him to the login screen. Only thing off from usual is that I'm using the # scheme, because this app has to play nicely with other code in the same web server.

Expected behaviour: Login screen appears.

Actual behaviour: Routed "nowhere". I sit looking at a blank screen.

Route Guard:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthenticationService } from './authentication.service';

import {
    CanActivate, Router,
    ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    RouterStateSnapshot
    } from '@angular/router';
import { GlobalsService } from "./globals.service";

@Injectable()
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private _service: AuthenticationService, private router: Router, private _globals: GlobalsService) {
        console.log("Auth Guard Ready!");
    }

    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Promise<boolean> {
        let url: string = state.url;
        return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
            if (this._service.checkLoggedIn()) {
                console.log("User is logged in, possible to check for globals");
                if (this._globals.globalsReady) {
                    console.log("Globals are already loaded, user may proceed to the page");
                    resolve(true);
                    return;
                }
                console.log("Globals are not ready yet, asking server for the data..");
                this._globals.getGlobals()
                    .done(() => {
                        console.log("Globals are now loaded, user may proceed to the page");
                        resolve(true); 
                    })
                    .error((error: any) => {
                        console.log("Error fetching globals. Navigation terminated");
                        console.log("Error: " + error);
                        resolve(false);
                        return;
                    });
            } else {
                // we couldnt find any way to auth, so sending user to login screen
                console.log("User is not logged in - sending user to login page, no need for globals there");
                this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you reach your login route normally without the guard ? Are you sure the issue is coming from it ?

Comment: You should also `resolve(false);` when the user is not logged in after redirecting.

Comment: Yes i can get to the login route normally, i'm 99% sure it is from the guard

Comment: thats was it, thanks @AlexBeugnet, please make it an answer and I'll accept :)

Comment: Sure, glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guard needs to know what to do for all cases.

Adding `resolve(false);` when the user is not logged in (after redirecting) will do the trick

Comment: i'm still kicking myself, its such a silly thing .. but there was no way i'd have seen it without help. It feels a little like i'm pioneering here, the resources online are all over the map (regarding versions) and this component (the routing) seems to have gone through some spectacular changes in its short history..

Comment: the take away here is that navigating doesn't "finish" the guard. you HAVE to provide a return value always..